# Flutter - how avoid pushing same route twice?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

This structure of my app navigation:

```
CupertinoTabScaffold ->tabBuilder:TabPage-> tabBar: CupertinoTabBar
```

My TabPage:

```
return MaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: navKey,    
  home: child,
);
```

I have separate navigation in each tab. by clicking on the bottom tab, I go back to the beginning. this is my code and this is working now:

```
 key.currentState!.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/', ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```

for each tab I have my own navigation key. I pass it to each TabPage.

but if the page is at the root I need to  avoid pushing same route twice. I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
  key.currentState!.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/",
    (route) => route.isFirst && route.settings.name == "/" ? false : true);
```

how avoid pushing same route twice?

Answer (score 3):

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
   "newRouteName",
   (route) => route.isCurrent && route.settings.name == "newRouteName"
  ? false
  : true);
```

t will pop the current route if name of the route is "newRouteName" and then push new one, else will not pop anything.

Edit: Latest flutter provides ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name to get the name of current route.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html), you can simply add a checker on `onTap()` to see if you're going to navigate on the same page. To track the current page, you can either use enum or a simple variables like int. [CupertinoTabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html) also have an onTap property available similar to BottomNavigationBar.

```dart
BottomNavigationBar(
  items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[...],
  currentIndex: _currentPage,
  onTap: (value){
    // Only navigate if a different page was clicked
    if(value != _currentPage){
      _currentPage = value;
      setState(() {
        switch(value) {
          // Page 0
          case 0:
            key.currentState!.pushReplacementNamed(...);
            break;
          // Page 1
          case 1:
            key.currentState!.pushReplacementNamed(...);
            break;
          
          ...
        }
      });
    }
  }
)
```

Or if you're using a TabBar with TabBarView, the page displayed can be managed by the controller as demonstrated in this [guide](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html).

Answer (score -1):

This will pop the current route if name of the route is the new Route Name and then push new one, else will not pop any route.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
  "new",
  (route) => route.isCurrent && ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name == "new"
      ? false
      : true);
```

Comment: how is this different from my version?